# Changing 'Administrator' profile location from different account on Server 2008 R2

Tags: user-accounts, administrator, windows-server-2008-r2, multi-boot

My laptop has dual boot with Server 2008 R2 and Ubuntu 10.04. I mounted the Windows system drive on Ubuntu for a moment last night and moved the folder containing my virtual machines to an external hard drive. And I unmounted it right away. But after I booted into Windows after that, it seems all settings for my "Administrator" account has vanished. The desktop wallpaper is gone, everything has 'Arial' and lots of services aren't running properly, it denies permission to do even the most basic of tasks. I can't find the installed themes, all pinned items are gone (taskbar + start menu), it seems everything's got "deleted" somehow.

Is there a way to revert/fix this?

P.S. In case it's relevant, I did have another account with admin rights and it's still working like before, with no changes in it whatsoever.

**Update:** The profile directory for 'Administrator' has somehow changed to 'C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile'. I have no idea why and how.... How do I change this from a different account with admin rights?

Comment: Why are you running server on your laptop as a dual boot?

Comment: @KronoS Because I can't afford a genuine Windows license. I got the server licenses from Dreamspark. Got Ubuntu lately to do some paid work as Dreamspark license prohibits commercial use without purchase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for permission problems using [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx), fixing them would recover from some issues.

Profile folders locations are in the registry, search for `systemprofile` in `HKEY_USERS`...

Comment: Strangely (or not so strangely), I found a backup of the 'Administrator' account in the registry. However it got made and however the main profile got mutated I have no idea.... Time to ask another question. Thanks for your help.